# пропорциональный рост значения в excel

Tags: excel, формулы

Добрый день, нужно посчитать зп сотрудникам. В ячейке e11 хранится процент выполнения плана.

нужно рассчитать % их премии. Вроде сделал все, до момента с пропорциональными процентами

```
=ЕСЛИ(E11<0,5;0;ЕСЛИ(E11<0,8;0,05;ЕСЛИ(E11<1;0,1;ЕСЛИ(E11<1,5; ТО ВОТ ЗДЕСЬ НУЖНО ИЗМЕНЕНИЕ;0,2))))
```

Само задание:

Выполнение от 0 до 50% = 0; выполнение от 51% до 80% = 5%; выполнение от 81% до 100% = 10%; выполнение от 101% до 150% = рост до 20% пропорционально выполнению плана

Comment: Вы правильный ответ-то выберете или сами не знаете какой из двух предложенных вариантов формулы верный? Или оба варианта вас не устраивают?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
=ЕСЛИ(E11<=0,5;0;ЕСЛИ(E11<=0,8;0,05;ЕСЛИ(E11<=1;0,1;ЕСЛИ(E11<=1,5;(E11*0,2)/1,5;0,2))))
```

Это доработка варианта в вопросе

Comment: Проверил все варианты, на текущий момент только эта формула отрабатывает корректно.

Comment: подтверждаю что это работает правильее

Answer (score 2):

```
(E11-1)*0,2+0,1
```

правда значение равное 0,2 вы сможете получить только при E11 = 1,5, что противоречит условию E11<1,5

Для наглядности, действие формулы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: что-то совсем не понял как это работает

Comment: Подставьте 1 - получите 0,1, подставьте 1,5 - получите 0,2. Разве не этого вы хотели?

Comment: Если больше 150% - что  тогда?

Comment: оно то считает правильно) Просто сам механизм понять не могу, чтобы потом опять не спрашивать)

Comment: если больше 150 - тоже 20%, показывает верно

Comment: @lion295, да 20%, просмотрел у вас значение из `иначе`.

Comment: К примеру, 140% выполненного плана - это 18,67% премии. По вашей формуле 18%. Это не верно!!! Или автор вопроса некорректно ставит задачу или не видит ошибку.

Comment: @АлександрПузанов, из вопроса я понял, что при плане от 100% до 150% премия должна вырасти с 10% до 20%. Это и написал в формуле.

Comment: Рост до 20 ПРОПОРЦИОНАЛЬНО выполнению плана. Если Автор вопроса доволен ответом, то он некорректно поставил сам вопрос. Я привел пример. Должно быть не 18, а 18,67. Это пропорционально, а в вашем варианте приблизительно пропорционально.

Comment: (E11*0,2)/1,5 - эта формула отрабатывает правильно.

Comment: @АлександрПузанов, что вы мне доказываете правильно/не правильно? Автор вопроса пусть решает как у него должна премия рассчитываться на участке от 100 до 150%.

Comment: Eсли такое вычисление некорректно, автору не составит труда изменить формулу самостоятельно. Тут главный вопрос - как вставить это условие в формулу.

Comment: Я привел пример, где видно, что ваша формула отрабатывает некорректно. Вам решать. А как вставить формулу - я привел в ответе.

Comment: @АлександрПузанов, с вашей позиции вы считаете свой ответ верным, но кто вам сказал, что работодатель начисляющий премию с вами согласен :) Ждите решения вопрошающего. P.S. Лучше бы диаграмму нарисовали для наглядности.

Comment: Я отталкиваюсь от поставленной задачи. Извини, но математически твое решение некорректно. )) С диаграммой шутка хорошая.

Comment: Пропорционально, это значит за каждый процент премии после 100% переработки составит   20% * x% / 150%. Если с математикой плохо, то уже не поспоришь и ничего не докажешь.

Comment: @АлександрПузанов, да я вам ни чего не доказываю, это вы что-то все на комментарии к моему ответу исходите.

Comment: График зачетный. Достойный ответ.